# How to get $* into a bash array

Tags: bash

I want to set up an array using command line parameters. The user can either provide a list of files or the script locates them somehow. So I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo given n=$#, v=$*
[ $# -gt 0 ] && files=(${*}) || files=(/tmp/cap*)
echo num files = ${#files[@]}
echo files = ${files[@]}
```

But when I run it with a file list, I get into trouble:

```
$ /tmp/foo a b '4 4 4' c d
given n=5, v=a b 4 4 4 c d
num files = 7
files = a b 4 4 4 c d
```

How do I effectively get `tmp=($*)`?

Comment: If the question is how to preserve the quoted argument then the answer is quote the expansion in the array assignment and don't use `$*` use `$@`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and I think now I also get all those man page remarks about ${xx[@]} versus ${xx[*]}...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
files=(${*})
```

with

```
files=("$@")
```

What's the difference between `$*` and `$@`? The bash man page says:

> #### `$*`
>
> Expands  to  the positional parameters, starting from one.  When the expansion is not within double quotes, each positional
>            parameter expands to a separate word.  In contexts where it is performed, those words are subject to further word splitting
>                 and pathname expansion.  When the expansion occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single word with the value of each
>                 parameter separated by the first character of the IFS special variable.  That is, `"$*"` is equivalent to `"$1c$2c..."`,  where
>                 c  is  the  first character of the value of the IFS variable.  If IFS is unset, the parameters are separated by spaces.  If
>                 IFS is null, the parameters are joined without intervening separators.
>
> #### `$@`
>
> Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one.  When the expansion occurs within double  quotes,  each  parameter
>                 expands  to  a separate word.  That is, `"$@"` is equivalent to `"$1" "$2"` ...  If the double-quoted expansion occurs within a
>                 word, the expansion of the first parameter is joined with the beginning part of the original word, and the expansion of the
>                 last  parameter  is  joined  with the last part of the original word.  When there are no positional parameters, `"$@"` and `$@`
>                 expand to nothing (i.e., they are removed).

You'll almost always want to use `"$@"` over `$@`, `"$*"`, or `$*`.

Answer (score 1):

```
c_star ()
{
    printf 'argc: %s\n' "$#";
    printf Unquoted\\n
    printf 'argv: %s\n' $*
    printf Quoted\\n
    printf 'argv: %s\n' "$*"
}

c_at ()
{
    printf 'argc: %s\n' "$#";
    printf Unquoted\\n
    printf 'argv: %s\n' $@
    printf Quoted\\n
    printf 'argv: %s\n' "$@"
}

$ c_star a b '4 4 4' c d
argc: 5
Unquoted
argv: a
argv: b
argv: 4
argv: 4
argv: 4
argv: c
argv: d
Quoted
argv: a b 4 4 4 c d
$ c_at a b '4 4 4' c d
argc: 5
Unquoted
argv: a
argv: b
argv: 4
argv: 4
argv: 4
argv: c
argv: d
Quoted
argv: a
argv: b
argv: 4 4 4
argv: c
argv: d
```

So, given the above, and that you want each argument as its own value in the array you want the expansion of `"$@"` so use `files=("$@")`.